# How to trigger a function before select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

How to Trigger an function before drop down of select and abort dropdown if returned false?

maybe something like this:

```
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{ 
 if(check()==false)
  e.target.abortdropdown();
})
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @YT_Xaos pretty self explanatory, I need to trigger a function when I click on <select> but it should trigger before the dropdown (possibly even prevent drop down)

Comment: might want to consider adding `disabled` to the select vs preventing it dropping down, else it will look broken or no items

Comment: you can bind "disabled" attribute with a variable whose value is controlled by a function you call on selecting the dropdown. 

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can put a container around the selectbox and bind it to the click event. then you check your check() function and can act on what happens to the select box. .

```js
let check = () => {return false;};

const w = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
const s = w.querySelector('select');

w.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
  const os = s.querySelectorAll('option');
  
  if(check() == false){    
    s.setAttribute('onclick',"abortdropdown()");
    console.log('check() is false');  
    abortdropdown(os);
    
  } else {
    console.log('check() is true');  
    setdropdown(os);
    
  }      
});  


function abortdropdown(os) {
  os.forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.add('hide');
  })  
}

function setdropdown(os) {
  os.forEach((el) => {
      el.classList.remove('hide');
  })        
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  
  <select >
    <option class="hide">1</option>
    <option class="hide">2</option>
    <option class="hide">3</option>
  </select>
  
</div>
```

### UPDATE

Here is a much better example. The wrapper / parent container (can also be your body) is triggered via mouseover in this example (load or similar would also fit). This checks your check() function. And would then set the selct box disabled or remove disabled. This should actually do what you want.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
const s = parent.querySelector('select');

let check = () => {return true;};

parent.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  
  if(check() == false){    
    s.setAttribute('disabled',"disabled");
    console.log('check() is false');      
    
  } else {
    console.log('check() is true');  
    s.removeAttribute('disabled')    
  }  
});
```

```css
select[disabled] {pointer-events:none}
```

```html
<div id="parent">  
  <select disabled>
    <option class="hide">1</option>
    <option class="hide">2</option>
    <option class="hide">3</option>
  </select>
  
</div>
```

Comment: how does this stop dropdown if check returns false?

Comment: @cakelover Hi! I will show you in a example. I updated my answear. it is a possibility. In this case i work with css `display:none` and js `classList` function.

Comment: @cakelover I add a secound example (under the point Update). It is better then to work with css. hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault.

Then the if inner case should be.

```
If (check==false) {
    e.target.preventDefault();
}
```

And that stops further default handling of the event.